# Why is there an accuracy output during the training phase of caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

Hello I have been using caffe just on the base dataset mnist and I am wondering why there is an accuracy output during training? Within the prototxt file lenet_train_test.protoxt the accuracy layer is

```
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

From the caffe Wiki it says that when I run caffe train I am explicitly stating to train in a particular phase and the same goes for caffe test. But why when I run caffe train am I still getting an accuracy when the layer for accuracy specifically says TEST?

Comment: can you post the full proto_test.protoxt, i suspect that there is a layer that has accuracy and has no include directive mentioned

Comment: can you also pleas post a portion of the output that shows the accuracy output during training.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `solver.prototxt`; there should be lines something like

```
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 50
```

These are periodic tests to check model convergence.  In this case, the tests are every 50 training iterations; the test consists of 1000 forward-pass iterations.  This is the source of your accuracy reports.  You should see the accuracy generally improving through the training.  When this accuracy plateaus, you've hit convergence -- further training will likely degrade accuracy, as you move into over-fitting.